# IOS limitation writing files in the sandbox

Tags: ios, sandbox

I'm trying to move some files between `/Documents` and `/Library` folders in my app sandbox but I'm running into an issue where every copy operation fails.

This simple code from a objective-c book works perfectly within a non - IOS related project:

```
    NSString          *dirName = @"testdir";
    NSString          *path;
    NSFileManager     *fm;            
    // Need to create an instance of the file manager            
    fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // Get current directory
    path = [fm currentDirectoryPath];
    NSLog (@"Current directory path is %@", path);
    // Create a new directory
    if ([fm createDirectoryAtPath: dirName withIntermediateDirectories: YES
                       attributes: nil error: NULL] == NO) {
        NSLog (@"Couldn't create directory!");
        return 1;
    }            
    // Rename the new directory           
    if ([fm moveItemAtPath: dirName toPath: @"newdir" error: NULL] == NO) {
        NSLog (@"Directory rename failed!");
        return 2;
    }            
    // Change directory into the new directory
    if ([fm changeCurrentDirectoryPath: @"newdir"] == NO) {
        NSLog (@"Change directory failed!");
        return 3;
    }           
    // Now get and display current working directory
    path = [fm currentDirectoryPath];
    NSLog (@"Current directory path is %@", path);
    NSLog (@"All operations were successful!");
}        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([writingAppDelegate class]));
```

...but does not work when embedded into a IOS app, returning the error:

`2013-12-23 14:37:32.781 writingTest[30972:70b] Couldn't create directory!`

Not sure if I'm missing any well known limitation on file operations allowed in a Iphone App Sandbox but I will appreciate your help.

Thanks,
     dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you aren't providing the full path to create directoryAtPath, so when the execution reaches this point:

```
if ([fm createDirectoryAtPath: dirName withIntermediateDirectories: YES
                       attributes: nil error: NULL] == NO) {
```

dirname contains "testdir", not the full path.

What you want to do is to get the Documents directory:

```
- (NSString *) applicationDocumentsDirectory 
{    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```

and then append the directory name you want to create:

```
if ([fm createDirectoryAtPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:dir] withIntermediateDirectories: YES
                           attributes: nil error: NULL] == NO) {
```

Check the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW12)